# SQL query NOT formating data to MM/DD/YYYY

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following query is not formatting the date `(12/9/2010)` in column `PROVISIONED_DATE` to `MM/DD/YYYY` like everyone on the internet says its suppose to.

SQL QUERY:

```
select convert(varchar(20),PROVISIONED_DATE,101) as 'DATE PROVISIONED'
from PEV.dbo.EVSE
where [SRC_SYS_ID] = '3297'
```

OUTPUT:

```
12/9/2010 12:46
```

EXPECTED RESULTS:

```
12/09/2010 12:46
```

based of this website: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx the following works great using GETDATE(), but when I change to my column_name it NO longer works

```
Date Format - MM/DD/YYYY
Standard - USA
SQL Statement - SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101) AS [MM/DD/YYYY]
Sample Output - 11/23/1998
```

Please Help!

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems - SQL is **NOT** a database product... stuff like this is very often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what database system you're using....

Comment: is provisioned_date a date column? varchar?

Comment: which database you use
oracle or sql server the above query works in sql server if it is sql server then try using 103 or 108 instead of 101 in convert

Comment: What is Data Type for PROVISIONED_DATE ?

Comment: Obviously this is SqlServer (not sure about version)

Comment: If you're using SQL Server, style 101 is a date-only format so would only give you "12/09/2010"

Comment: Why is `provisioned_date` not a date/time data type? If you think this is the last problem you'll come across because you chose the wrong type...

Answer (score 2):

I think data type for your column is not DateTime. Please try as follow.

```
 declare @dt varchar(20)
     set @dt = '12/9/2010'

     SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), convert(datetime,@dt), 101) AS [MM/DD/YYYY]
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the datatype of your `PROVISIONED_DATE`? Try following

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(20),CAST('12/9/2010' as DATETIME),101)
```

Result is 12/09/2010 as expected.

That means `PROVISIONED_DATE` is not a `DATETIME` column

So try to cast before convert as above.